# Animation not apply second time on button click

Tags: android, animation, image-rotation

I have issue that my animation is not apply second time on button click. I have used [this](https://github.com/florent37/ViewAnimator) library.I want rotation of image with animation. but problem is that it working only once.

**here is my code on button click**

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 ViewAnimator.animate(imageView)
                        .rotation(rotationAngle).duration(1000)
                         .repeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART)
                        .start();
                if(rotationAngle==360)
                {
                    rotationAngle=180;
                }
                else
                {
                    rotationAngle += 180;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: the link you are providing is not working any more

Comment: what is the initial value you are setting for rotationAngle variable?

Comment: 180 @AbdulWaheed

Comment: Try with clearing animation of the view before applying new animation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code that is working fine and I have tested as well

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int rotationAngle = 180;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_testing);

    findViewById(R.id.btn_click).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ViewAnimator.animate(tv)
                    .rotation(rotationAngle).duration(1000)
                    .repeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART)
                    .start();

            if(rotationAngle==360)
            {
                rotationAngle=180;
            }
            else
            {
                rotationAngle += 180;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Hope that helps you too

Answer (score 0):

I test this code and seems it working properly. If you want always rotating image  at clockwise try next:
Init default value of rotationAngle

```
 private float rotationAngle=179.99f;
```

.99f - because 360 degrees is 0 degrees and you need some less for rotation in same direction

Then set onClickListener:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ViewAnimator.animate(imageView)
                        .rotation(rotationAngle).duration(1000)
                        .repeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART)
                        .start();
                if(rotationAngle>=360)
                {
                    rotationAngle=179.99f;
                }
                else
                {
                    rotationAngle += 180;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because you used

```
ViewAnimator.animate(imageView)
                        .rotation(rotationAngle).duration(1000)
```

You should use

```
ViewAnimator.animate(imageView).rotationBy(rotationAngle)....
```

The reason why it only worked once is that if you used rotation, it will rotate to the degree of the rotation(180 for your case) since the activity created instead of current position.